# Nested foreach with Stream API

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have a case where A has a list of B and B has some property i need.

```
pseudocode structure
class A
   List<B> elements;

class B
   Property property;
```

I have List of A. In order, to get property i should go through the double foreach loop to get the property i want. Like this:

```
String myFutureProp = null;
for (A a: list of A) {
    for(B b: list of B) {
       if("MY_PROPERTY".equals(b.getKey) {
           myFutureProp = b.getValue();   
       }
    }
}
```

I was thinking to get it more tasty using Stream API. I was looking forward with 
forEach() solution:

```
final String[] myFutureProp = {null}
    a.getElements()
               .foreach(b -> b.getElements().stream()
                      .filter("MY_PROPERTY"::equals)
                      .forEach(prop -> myFutureProp[0] = (String)prop.getValue);
```

Then i'm taking myFutureProp[0] but it looks ugly to be honest. Is it any another solution in Stream API that i'm able to use?

Comment: If B lists are values of A list?

Comment: Your two snippets are not consistent. Are you starting with a list of A elements or with a single `A` instance? And what is `b.getElements()`?

Comment: A has List<B> bElements, B has Property. In this case i have List of A.

Comment: So B has a single Property having a getKey() and getValue() methods?

Comment: @Eran yes, that first case was just a pseudo code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I got your class structure right.

You can use `flatMap` to get a `Stream` of all the `Property`s of all the `B` instances, and return any property having the required key (if found) :

```
Optional<String> myFutureProp =
    aList.stream()
         .flatMap(a->a.getElements().stream().map(B::getProperty))
         .filter(prop->prop.getKey().equals("MY_PROPERTY"))
         .map(Property::getValue)
         .findAny();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do a work -> get last matching value

```
final String value = bList.stream()
    .flatMap(bElement -> bElement.elements().stream())
    .map(aElement -> aElement.getProperty())
    .filter(property -> property.getKey().equals("MY_PROPERTY"))
    .map(property -> property.getValue())
    .reduce((a,b) -> b).orElse(null);
```